# Error connecting to remote server via https from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl

I know that there are already responses to problems like this, but until now the solutions have not worked for me.

I have a nodejs server that work like a proxy. I need to connect to a server via https. I use https module of node with the following options:

```
var openidmConnection = {
  hostname: 'remoteserver',
  port: 8443,
  path: 'path/to/resource',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headersObject,
  key: private_pem_key,
  requestCert: connectionOptions.requestCert,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  agent: false,
  secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method',
  secureOptions: 'SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3|SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2',
}
```

When I test with postman to my local node server that make this call, I have an error saying:

`EPROTO 140482007910272:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number`

I searched and I found that errors with `SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number` can be because I am trying to connect to wrong port, or the host not support https, or use http module instead of https. None of these applies to me, since I verified that the host support https, the port is 8443 and the module is https. I am using node 0.12.6

Comment: Why the downvote? At least tell me the reason to avoid downvotes in the future. I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You're forcing SSLv3 usage and the remote party does not support it. Which isn't surprising considering the security issues SSLv3 (and SSLv2) has. Try setting `secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'` instead to force TLSv1.

You can also remove `requestCert` since that is a server-side option.

Comment: Thank for answer, I changed `secureProtocol` to `'TLSv1_method'` and now I have an error `socket hang up` with code `ECONNRESET`. Any idea why or how to deal with the problem?

Comment: Did you try without setting `key: private_pem_key`? Is the path right (normally it starts with a forward slash)? Are you able to curl the server successfully with the same settings?

Comment: The path is right, it is `/info/login`, I also try without `key: private_pem_key` and without `requestCert` and `rejectUnauthorized` options, and I can connect to the server succesfully using openssl in ubuntu 14.04.  The command is some like `openssl s_client -port 8443 -key private_pem_key -host remoteserver`. I want to note that if execute the command without the `-key private_pem_key` parameter, I can connect too.